# Run a function when another function is already running

Tags: c++, c++17

I have created a function `Listener((*insert)(),(*eject)())` which accepts two call back functions `insert` and `eject`. The function `Listener` listens to any hardware change like a usb plugged in or plugged out. Whenever a device is connected, the call back function insert is called and whenever a device is plugged out the eject method is called. So the Listener method runs as soon as the code is run and keeps running till I close the console.
Now I want to use a method say `UserDecision()` which would ask user if they want do something from a list of option. I want this function to run regardless of the `listener` function running. So basically I want to run two functions simultaneously.
Give me a direction on ways this may be done

Comment: `std::thread`, for instance?

Comment: Ok thread can do that... thanks.

Comment: In C++20 you will also have [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) as a mechanism to consider.